# Attaining Explicit and Predictable Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

I need help, how can I learn this framework?

Here's what I need to know.

- Routes, its expected outcome, the prefix/suffix methods associated with every changes made with it.
- ActiveRecord, the dynamic generation of methods, the behind the scenes with prefix_ and _suffix methods.
- The View, how do I know what prefix/suffix methods can be used in the View.

Is there's a way to know all those behind-the-scenes actions in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the output of the `rake routes` command sufficient? It should give you every possible route method name, and to where that route maps.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it using rake -T, however, in some examples, I can see '@comment, :comment, comment' to reference those objects, which is which?